# What should I know to publsh a new paperback from KDP

Tags: publishing, ebook

For the past few days I have had zero access to CreateSpace; nothing else under createspace.com has given me a webpage, even an error page.

What is going on now?

How good or bad are Amazon KDP for converting the HTML input to KDP into a good paperback?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Jonathan, you may have more luck on Facebook's SPF Community than here for getting an answer to this question. The writers there are hardcore self-publishers and should be able to help you: https://www.facebook.com/groups/SPFsecretgroup/

Comment: Hi Jonathan.  This is really two separate questions.  The first one is a customer service question for Amazon, it is not a good question for our site, so I would suggest editing to just focus on the second question.

Comment: Createspace and KDP are merging. They may have started transferring books over to the KDP platform, which is why Createspace may be squirrelly right now. Their time line for merging sounds a bit vague, but what I heard from my publisher is "over the next few weeks."

Answer (score 2):

Kevin,

I recently self-published a book through KDP from a Microsoft Word Document. They offer a free, easy to follow step-by-step guide that answers all formatting questions. The process was easy, I've sold about 100 books with a few sales in Europe and India (???) Don't know if this answers your questions but good luck.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

CreateSpace is being discontinued.

A copy of an email to me from CreateSpace Aug 28th, 2018

> Hello,
>
> We’re excited to announce that CreateSpace (CSP) and Kindle Direct
>   Publishing (KDP) will become one service, and in the coming days, we
>   will give CreateSpace members the ability to move their account and
>   titles. To ensure a quality experience, we will add links to the
>   CreateSpace member dashboard in phases so authors may see it at
>   different times. As a reminder, Kindle Direct Publishing (KDP) now
>   offers Expanded Distribution to sell your paperbacks to physical
>   bookstores in the US, as well as the ability to sell your paperback
>   books on Amazon.ca and Amazon.com.au (Amazon.mx coming soon). With
>   these features, KDP’s paperback distribution will be on par with
>   CreateSpace’s distribution. KDP also offers features that aren’t
>   available on CreateSpace. These include the ability to purchase ads to
>   promote paperbacks on Amazon.com and locally printed author copies in
>   Europe.
>
> As a result of these enhancements to KDP and our ongoing efforts to
>   provide a more seamless experience for managing your paperback and
>   digital books, CreateSpace and KDP will become one service. On KDP,
>   your paperbacks will still be printed in the same facilities, on the
>   same printers, and by the same people as they were on CreateSpace.
>
> In a few weeks, we’ll start automatically moving your CreateSpace
>   books to KDP. Your books will remain available for sale throughout the
>   move and you’ll continue to earn royalties. Once we begin this process
>   you’ll be unable to edit existing titles or create new titles on
>   CreateSpace.
>
> If you have a release planned soon or you would like to start the move
>   yourself, we are making updates that will allow you to move your
>   entire catalog in just a few steps. During this transition, you can
>   contact KDP customer support by email and access phone support in
>   English.
>
> There are a few payment and printing fee differences associated with
>   the move. Going forward you will be paid on KDP’s payment schedule.
>   CreateSpace pays monthly royalties 30 days after the end of the month
>   in which they were earned while KDP pays monthly royalties
>   approximately 60 days after the end of the month in which they were
>   earned. As a result, you’ll be paid in September for any royalties
>   earned in August on CreateSpace and be paid in October for any
>   royalties earned in August on KDP. In addition, some low-page count
>   books will see an increase in printing fees when they are printed in
>   the UK and EU. This affects a small number of titles. If your titles
>   are affected by this change, you will receive a separate email on this
>   topic. Learn more about KDP’s printing fees here.
>
> To learn more about the move and review the latest, visit here. We’ll
>   be in touch with more updates in the coming weeks.
>
> It is still Day 1 for independent publishing. As Amazon’s recent
>   shareholder letter noted, there are more than a 1,000 authors who earn
>   more than a $100,000 a year from their work with us. We could not be
>   more optimistic about the future of independent publishing and this
>   change will allow us to innovate faster for you.
>
> Best Regards, The CreateSpace and KDP Team
>
> This email was sent by: CreateSpace